# Dialogflow caches webhook request session

Tags: django, cookies, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow V1 with Django as the webhook target. The trouble I am having is that one of the Dialogflow servers somehow caches the cookie/sessionid and sends to the webhook every time, which is wrong.

In one of the webhook calls, my server creates a new user and logs in the user which in turn writes sessionid to the request cookie. Somehow the session/cookie will be cached by that particular DialogFlow server, and that server always sends the same sessionid/cookie to the webhook. With the sessionid, Django auto-login the request with the same user, which causes problems.

I tried the flowing ways to remove the cached cookie, but all failed

1. unset cookies
2. logout user: logout(request)
3. try to find a config in Dialogflow

Interestingly, only that particular server sends the wrong request, which causes our chat breaks intermittently.

Comment: Can you share some code Andy, so we give more helpful advice?

Comment: @lukedavis unfortunately we have migrated away from Dialogflow due to this bug among other reasons. We do not have the code anymore. Having that said, the code we used was just standard Django login(request), and then the following requests from that particular IP will always be logged in, which caused problem.